# Find Conflicting files while merging two git branches

Tags: git, git-merge, git-diff, git-merge-conflict, github-desktop

I have my main branch 'master' and two derived branches 'branch-a' and 'branch-b'. when i try to merge 'branch-a' in 'branch-b' github desktop checks: [image]
and shows that there will be two conflicting files, these could be code files or dll or images, i don't know:
[image]
and when i click 'merge' it shows that files have been merged automatically.

i want to know which files were conflicting?

i have multiple features in my software, and i cannot test whole application to find which module is corrupted by this merge. maybe git have taken 'branch-a' code/dll/image and discarded 'branch-b' code/dll/image? i don't know. i just want the names of files which were conflicting. mostly it happens with dll/Libraries.

Comment: What is this GUI tool that fails to show this info? Don’t use it any longer, it’s clearly no good. And are you sure the conflict was resolved? I bet it wasn’t. Use the command line and ask for git status.

Comment: its 'github desktop' : https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: Well, throw it away. Learn to use the command line. Or use a better GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way is to search for conflict markers in your files : `"<<<<"` or `">>>>"`

If you find none : `git` probably chose a way to combine these would've conflicts.

---

Suppose your commits are named as below :

```
* mmmm (HEAD -> branch-b) Merged branch 'branch-a' into branch-b
|\
| * aaaa (branch-a) commit on branch-a
* | bbbb commit on branch-b
...
```

You can view :

```
# diff with branch-a
git diff --name-status aaaa mmmm
# rather than typing explicit commit hashes, you can also type :
git diff --name-status HEAD^2 HEAD

# diff with branch-b
git diff --name-status bbbb mmmm
# same as :
git diff --name-status HEAD^1 HEAD
```

If a file name appears in the diff with `branch-a`, and not in the diff with `branch-b` :
this means that the merge resulted in keeping the version from `branch-b`.

Conversely : if a name appears in the diff with `branch-b` but not in the diff with `branch-a` :
the merge kept the version from `branch-a`.

If a name appears in *both* lists :
this means that `git` combined both contents to create the merge.

---

You can reduce the scope of files to list to a directory or a specific file :

```
git diff --name-status HEAD^1 HEAD -- code/dll/
git diff --name-status HEAD^1 HEAD -- code/dll/image
```

Comment: it seems its not a code conflict, code conflict is shown by  >>>> and <<<<. supposedly its a conflict in Library/Image/Binary file. there are 1400 files being merged, i cannot check each file.

Answer (score 1):

You can just go ahead and hit "Merge branch-a into branch-b" that the very next thing GitHub Desktop will do is to show you the conflicting files and allow you to resolve the conflicts before actually committing the merge. You will also have the option to abort the merge, as shown on the image below:

[image]